# (C++) Need to figure out all points within a radius using reg. 2D windows coord. system

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-c++

Sorry in advance, I'm struggling a bit with how to explain this... :)

Essentially, I've got a typical windows coordinate system (the Top, Left is 0,0). If anybody's familiar with the haversine query, [like in SQL](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,238858,238858), it can get all points in a radius based on latitude and longitude coordinates.

I need something much simpler, but my math skills ain't all up to par! Basically, I've got random points scattered throughout about a 600x400 space. I have a need to, for any X,Y point on the map, run a query to determine how many other points are within a given radius of that one.

If that's not descriptive enough, just let me know!

Comment: Are you doing this once, or several times with the same data?

Comment: lots of times concurrently with multiple datas

Comment: You guys are scary fast. Excellent!! Thank you so much!

Comment: What's wrong with Ates Goral's answer? It's much more complete than mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Pythagoras:

```
distance = sqrt(xDifference^2 + yDifference^2)
```

Note that '^' in this example means "to the power of" and not C's bitwise XOR operator. In other words the idea is to square both differences.

Comment: Just for clarity "x^2" means "bitwise XOR x and 2."  That will compile, but doesn't give you the square (which is easiest as x * x).

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the confusion, my answer isn't actually in C++. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 12):

Straightforward approach:

You can calculate the distance between to points using the [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Distance_in_Cartesian_coordinates):

```
deltaX = x1 - x2
deltaY = y1 - y2
distance = square root of (deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY)
```

Given point `x1,y1`, do this for every other point (`x2,y2`) to see if the calculated distance is within (less than or equal to) your radius.

If you want to make it speedier, calculate and store the square of the radius and just compare against `(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY)`, avoiding the square root.

Comment: You forgot to square the deltas.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that on my own and fixed it immediately (but apparently I'm not faster than you guys). Thanks! :)

Comment: If delta is known to be a mostly small integer value like pixels you can build a lookup table of squares and square roots.  May or may not be faster than all the multiply operations.

Answer (score 5):

Before doing the Pythagoras, you could also quickly eliminate any point that falls outside of the square that can fully contain the target circle.

```
// Is (x1, y1) in the circle defined by center (x,y) and radius r
bool IsPointInCircle(x1, y1, x, y, r)
{
    if (x1 < x-r || x1 > x+r)
       return false;
    if (y1 < y-r || y1 > y+r)
       return false;
    return (x1-x)*(x1-x) + (y1-y)*(y1-y) <= r*r
}
```

Comment: This is probably an unnecessary optimization that might in fact be adding overhead. Note that multiplication isn't that costly for modern CPUs. In an attempt to avoid the two multiplications, you're introducing at least 8 subtractions and 4 conditional branches, which will cost clock cycles.

Comment: It may depend on how much data there is (obviously you'd have to try it and see what happens).  I've done this exact thing with impressive savings, but that was on a much older architecture (where missing a branch prediction wasn't such a big deal, and multiplications were quite expensive).

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about relative distance you shouldn't use square root you can do something like:

```
 rSquared = radius * radius #square the radius
 foreach x, y in Points do
   dX = (x - centerX) * (x - centerX) #delta X
   dY = (y - centerY) * (y - centerY) #delta Y
   if ( dX + dY <= rSquared ) then
     #Point is within Circle
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [equation for a circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equation):

```
radius ** 2 = (x - centerX) ** 2 + (y - centerY) ** 2
```

We want to find if a point `(x, y)` is inside of the circle.  We perform the test using this equation:

```
radius ** 2 < (x - centerX) ** 2 + (y - centerY) ** 2

// (Or use <= if you want the circumference of the circle to be included as well)
```

Simply substitute your values into that equation.  If it works (the inequality is true), the point is inside of the circle.  Otherwise, it isn't.